# "insert duplicate" two tickets to execute a script

Tags: php, mysql

once again, an apology for my English, I use google translator to write this. 
I am creating a small script to manage users. 
I happen to have a few small tables that have related to the main table is "usuarios".

The point is that when running my script, I inserted the same user twice. 
When you "echo" in the query functions not duplicate, is very strange because in the phpmyadmin does not happen, only with my script.

Here I leave my code:

```
function ar($a, $d = true){ // function test only
    if($d){
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($a);
        echo '</pre>';  
    }else{
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($a);    
        echo '</pre>';  
    }
}

function SecureData($data){//cleaning up the data that will be inserted
    global $conn;
    if(is_array($data)){
            foreach($data as $key=>$val){
                    if(!is_array($data[$key])){
                            $data[$key] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data[$key]);
                    }else{
                        $data[$key] = SecureData($data[$key]);
                    }
            }
    }else{
            $data = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data);
    }
    return $data;
}
//---->
function comillas($data, $s = "'"){// Wrap the string with a character
    if(is_array($data)){
            foreach($data as $key=>$val){
                    if(!is_array($data[$key])){
                            $data[$key] = $s.$data[$key].$s;
                    }else{
                        $data[$key] = comillas($data[$key]);
                    }
            }
    }else{
            $data = $s.$data.$s;
    }
    return $data;
}
//---->
function error_mysql($conn = ''){// Evalua y returna un error en la consulta si la hay
    if( mysqli_errno($conn) ){
     return "<pre>Errror en la consulta \n \t".mysqli_error($conn)."</pre>";
    }
    return false;
}
//---->
function updateTable($data = null){ // insert, update or delete a row in a certain table
    global $conn;
    $data = SecureData( $data );
    if( $data["action"] == "new" && !empty( $data["table"] ) ){

        $rows = implode(", ", comillas(array_keys( $data["values"] ), "`") );
        $values = implode(", ", comillas($data["values"]) );
        $s = "INSERT INTO `". $data["table"]."`(". $rows .") VALUES(". $values .");";
//      echo $s.'<br>'; return true;
        $q = mysqli_query($conn, $s);
        if( !$q ){
            echo error_mysql( $conn );
            return false;
        } 
        return mysqli_insert_id($conn);

    }else if( $data["action"] == "delete" && !empty($data["id"]) ){

        return mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM `". $data["table"] ."` WHERE id='". $data["id"] ."'");

    }else if( $data["action"] == "update" && !empty($data["table"]) && !empty($data["values"]) ){

        foreach(array_keys( $data["values"] ) as $v){
            $t[] = "`".$v."` = '" . $data["values"][$v] . "'";      
        }
        $t = implode(", ", $t );
        $s = "UPDATE `". $data["table"] ."` SET ". $t ." WHERE id = '". $data["id"] ."'";
        echo $s; return false;
        return mysqli_query($conn, $s);

    }else{
        return false;   
    }
}
// -->
function register_user($data = null){ // logs the user
    global $conn;
    if( !is_array( $data ) || empty( $data ) ){ return false; }
    $data = SecureData($data);
    $privacidad = updateTable( array("table"=> "privacidad", "action" => "new", "values" => array("busqueda" =>"publico", "visible" => "publico") ) );
    if( !$privacidad ){ return false; }
    $ubicacion = updateTable( array("table"=> "ubicacion", "action" => "new", "values" => array("pais" =>0, "estado" => 0, "municipio" => 0) ) );
    if( !$ubicacion){ 
        updateTable( array("table"=> "privacidad", "id" => $privacidad, "action" => "delete" ) );
    }
    $tour = updateTable( array("table"=> "tour", "action" => "new", "values" => array("foto" =>0, "verificado" => 0, "emailverificado" => 0) ) );
    if( !$tour){ 
        updateTable( array("table"=> "privacidad", "id" => $privacidad, "action" => "delete" ) ); 
        updateTable( array("table"=> "ubicacion", "id" => $ubicacion, "action" => "delete" ) ); 
        return false; 
    }

    $premium = updateTable( 
        array("table"=> "premium", "action" => "new", "values" => array("mensajes" =>0, "fotografias" => 0, "eventos" => 0, "reputacion" =>0, "busqueda" =>0, "visitas" => 0) ) );
    if( !$premium){ 
        updateTable( array("table"=> "privacidad", "id" => $privacidad, "action" => "delete" ) ); 
        updateTable( array("table"=> "ubicacion", "id" => $ubicacion, "action" => "delete" ) ); 
        updateTable( array("table"=> "tour", "id" => $tour, "action" => "delete" ) ); 
        return false; 
    }
    $new = updateTable(array(
                            "action" => "new",
                            "table" => "usuarios",
                            "values" => array(
                                            "nick" => $data["nick"],
                                            "email"  =>  $data["email"] ,
                                            "password"  =>  $data["password"] ,
                                            "usertype"  =>  $data["usertype"] ,
                                            "avatar"  =>  0 ,
                                            "status"  =>  1 ,
                                            "online"  => time() ,
                                            "privacidad"  =>  $privacidad ,
                                            "ubicacion"  =>  $ubicacion ,
                                            "tour"  =>  $tour ,
                                            "premium" =>  $premium ,
                                            "picpoints"  => 0
                                        )
                            )
                        );
        if( !$new ){
            echo $error;
            updateTable( array("table"=> "privacidad", "id" => $privacidad, "action" => "delete" ) ); 
            updateTable( array("table"=> "ubicacion", "id" => $ubicacion, "action" => "delete" ) ); 
            updateTable( array("table"=> "tour", "id" => $tour, "action" => "delete" ) ); 
            updateTable( array("table"=> "premium", "id" => $premium, "action" => "delete" ) );
            return false;
        } 
        return mysqli_insert_id($conn);

}
//---->
$conn = mysqli_connect(SDB, UDB, PDB, DB);// Connect to the database
if (!$conn) {
    printf("Conexi&oacute;n fallida: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");// We define that we use utf8 as encoding
$register = register_user(array('nick'=>'admin',  'email'=>'king.jorhel@gmail.com',  'password'=>'asdasd',  'usertype'=>'user'));
ar( $register );
mysqli_close($conn);
```

here the structure of the tables I use:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `premium` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `credito` float(6,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `mensajes` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fotografias` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `eventos` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reputacion` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `busqueda` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `visitas` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `privacidad`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `privacidad` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `busqueda` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `visible` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `tour`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tour` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `foto` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `verificado` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `emailverificado` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `ubicacion`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ubicacion` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pais` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `estado` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `municipio` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `usuarios`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usuarios` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nick` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(320) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `usertype` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  `online` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ubicacion` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tour` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `privacidad` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `premium` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `avatar` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `picpoints` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;
```

Comment: I do not see anything, which could explain your problem. Your code seems correct, but complicated. By the way you apply `SecureData` twice. The first time inside of `register_user` and the second time inside of `updateTable`.

Comment: You're right, I use it twice. in register_user He should not be. 
But I do not understand why duplicate entry :(

Comment: I do not see anything wrong. Are you sure you execute the code only once? Or maybe you press the button twice?

Comment: there is no form, it is a test file, only comes on and ready.

Comment: You already inserted debug output near `mysql_query`. If the query is printed only once, then it is also only executed once. Maybe the rows in the table are old rows you are seeing? Try to empty the table, then run the script again and see if there are really two rows then.

Comment: tables are new, I have created for testing purposes, no more than 2 days of life. D:

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**: In mysql, add the field "email" the "unique" property thus inserted only once